# How to get back to switch in c++

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to go back to switch after every case and I can't figure it out. I've tried with return but I can return just to main and it doesn't save the values from v[i]. Here is the code. The code itself should represent how RAM works on 8 bit. Also, v[0] should be between 0 and 19 and v[0]+v[1] should be less than 19 and I don't know how to implement that.

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char v[20];
    int pc,
    functie,
    n,
    i,
    loop;
    do {
        cout << "Este pornit calculatorul? (0/1) ";
        cin >> pc;
    }
    while ( pc != 1 );
    cout << "Ce functie selectati? 1-4 ";
    cin >> functie;
    switch (functie) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Citire din memorie" << endl;
        cout << "Cate numere cititi din memorie: ";
        cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << v[i];
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Scriere in memorie" << endl;
        cout << "Cate numere scrieti ";
        cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "v[" << i << "]= ";
            cin >> v[i];
        }

        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Golirea memoriei";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v[i] = '\0';
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Oprirea calculatorului";
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Nu ati selectat nici o functie";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a loop around the switch. `return 0;` from `main()` means exit the program which seems to be the opposite of what you want.

Comment: consider a `while` loop around the `switch`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Also i want v[0] to be between 0 and 19 and v[0]+v[1] <= 19. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Why did you bunch up all of your variables at the top of `main` instead of scoping them normally?

Comment: That s how someone edited the code, is not that important, i will change it later @Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch should be included in a loop if you want to iterate over it multiple times.

Also you should not generally include vulgar language in your code, even if it is not in English (6th variable you declared).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i've changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I managed to do the code but i still need to have v[0] between 0 and 19 and v[0]+v[1] <=19 and i don't know how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
char v[20];
        int pc, functie, n, i,loop;
 do {
                cout << "Este pornit calculatorul? (0/1) ";
                cin >> pc;
        }
        while (pc != 1);

       while(loop=1)
       {
            cout << "Ce functie selectati? 1-4 ";
            cin >> functie;
          switch (functie) {
        case 1:
                cout << "Citire din memorie" << endl;
                cout << "Cate numere cititi din memorie: ";
                cin >> n;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        cout << "v[" << i << "]="<<v[i]<<" ";
                        cout<<endl;
                    }
                break;
        case 2:
                cout << "Scriere in memorie"<<endl;
                cout << "Cate numere scrieti ";
                cin >> n;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        cout << "v[" << i << "]= ";
                        cin >> v[i];
                }
               break;
        case 3:
                cout << "Golirea memoriei";
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    v[i]='\0';
                    cout<<endl;
                break;
        case 4:
                cout << "Oprirea calculatorului";
                exit(0);
                break;
        default:
                cout << "Nu ati selectat nici o functie";
        }
       }


}
```

Comment: `while (loop = 1)` will assign the value of `1` to `loop` and then always evaluate to `true` That's an infinite loop. You want to make a `bool loop = true;` statement above your loop, and then your conditional becomes `while (loop) {...`. In your logic you set `loop = false;` when you're ready to exit.

Comment: Please only post answers if you are answering the question with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `goto` to jump at starting point of `switch` or any function for sake of simplicity. Consider the following code:

```
loop:
    switch(...) {
        case ...
        break;
    }

    goto loop;
```

Note that it's not always good to use the `goto`, it may throw serious problems in programs in some situations. Alternatively, you can do the same with `for` in a very convenient way. The example:

```
for(; ;)  
{  
    // body of the for loop.  
}
```

Hope you understand.